# Game programming without a main loop

Tags: pygame

My professor gave my class an assignment today based on object oriented programming in Pygame. Basically he has said that the game that we are to create will be void of a main game loop.  While I believe that it is possible to do this (and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565677/why-a-main-game-loop-is-necessary-for-developing-a-game) has stated that it is possible) I don't believe that this is required for adherence to the Object Oriented paradigm.

In a diagram that the professor gave, he showed the game initializing and as the objects were instantiated the control flow of the program would be distributed among the objects.

Basically I believe it would be possible to implement a game this way, but it would not be an ideal way nor is it required for Object Oriented adherence. Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** We are creating an asteroids clone, which I believe further complicates things due to the fact that it is a real time action game.

Comment: Hm, while I see how this could work, I just can't see how it would perform good when there are lots and lots of asteroids. Which one is going to check for collision? Each one on its own? Then which one is going to update the quadtree to avoid unnecessary collision checks? And having the entities manipulate some kind of global state isn't the best design choice either IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turn based games or anything event driven would be the route to go. In other words, take desktop GUI apps. They'll just tick (wait) over until an event is fired. The same could be done for a simple game. Take Checkers for example. Looping each game cycle would be overkill. 90% of the time the game will be static. Using some form of events (the [observer design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern would be nice here) would provide a much better solution. You're using Pygame, so there may be support for this built in, through due to my limited use I cannot comment fully. Either way, the general principles are the same.

All in all it's a pretty rubbish assignment if you ask me. If it's to teach you event driven programming, a simple GUI application would be better. Even the simplest of games us a basic game loop, which can adhere to OO principles.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was basically thinking. Thanks for the observer design idea, gonna use it.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.  In the general case, I think this idea is probably hokum.  SDL (upon which PyGame is implemented), provides information to the program via an event queue, and consuming that queue requires some sort of repeatedly checking the queue for events, processing them, and waiting until the next event arrives.

There are some particular exceptions to this, though.  You can poll the mouse and keyboard for their state without accessing the event queue.  The problem with that is it still requires something like a loop, so that it happens over and over again until the game exits.

You could use `pygame.time` to wait on a timer instead of waiting on the event queue, and then pass control to the game objects which poll the mouse and keyboard as per above, but you are still 'looping', but bound by a timer instead of the event queue.

Instead of focusing on eliminating a main loop, how about instead think about using it in an object oriented way.

For instance, you could require a 'root' object, which actually has its own event loop, but instead of performing any action based on the incoming events, it calls a handler on several child objects. For instance when the root object recieves a `pygame.event.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event, it could search through it's children for a 'rect' attribute and determine if the `event.pos` attribute is inside that rect.  if it is it can call a hypothetical onClick method on that child object.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might qualify as event driven programming? Which can still be object oriented. You see this in Flash a lot.

There's a difference between a main loop in a main class. You can still have a game class initialize all of your objects, and then rely on inputs to move the game onward.

Kinda hard to say exactly without knowing the exact parameters of your assignment, the devil is in the details.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at how python utilizes signals.  A decent example I found is at: http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html